# Hadoop HA (2.6.4): Standby namenode stuck in safe mode

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, bigdata

trying to get an HA configuration going on my cluster. I managed to get more of the configuration done on what was an active cluster. At this point, i have two NN's up and running, one is active, second is on standby. But, the secondary node is stuck in safe mode. Also, the primary namenode also went into safe mode when i started it, but using the -safemode leave command, i managed to get it working again (and then transitioned it to active).

I'm using three journal nodes which are active with the primary NN

here is the log from the secondary namenode:

```
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 787 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 787.
The number of live datanodes 0 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.
2016-05-22 15:33:35,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Edits file http://xxxxxxxyyyy:8480/getJournal?jid=Foundation&segmentTxId=94718&storageInfo=-60%3A2109188697%3A0%3ACID$
2016-05-22 15:33:35,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer: Loaded 7 edits starting from txid 94717
2016-05-22 15:35:35,156 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer: Triggering log roll on remote NameNode zzzzzzz.zzzz.zzz/10.0.0.4:54310
2016-05-22 15:35:35,386 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Reading org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream@4656dc3a expecting start txid #94725
2016-05-22 15:35:35,386 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Start loading edits file http://xxxxxx:8480/getJournal?jid=Foundation&segmentTxId=94725&storageInfo=-60%3A2109188697%$
2016-05-22 15:35:35,386 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream: Fast-forwarding stream 'http://xxxxxx:8480/getJournal?jid=Foundation&segmentTxId=94725&storageInfo=-60%3A2$
2016-05-22 15:35:35,386 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream: Fast-forwarding stream 'http://xxxxxx:8480/getJournal?jid=Foundation&segmentTxId=94725&storageInfo=-60%3A2$
2016-05-22 15:35:35,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode ON.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 787 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 787.
The number of live datanodes 0 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.
2016-05-22 15:35:35,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Edits file http://xxxxxx:8480/getJournal?jid=Foundation&segmentTxId=94725&storageInfo=-60%3A2109188697%3A0%3ACID-f5cb$
2016-05-22 15:35:35,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer: Loaded 7 edits starting from txid 94724
```